# Can we solve backward heat equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I am reading a paper. 
In the proof, there is the following claim:

> For any $t_0>0$, let $h$ be any positive function. We solve the backward heat equation starting from $t_0$ with initial data $h$. We then have that....

By some calculation. Then the author went on and show that for any time $t$, $\int_M h f \le 0$ acturally implies $f$ itself is nonpositive. I think in general one can not solve the backward heat equation. What is the problem?

Comment: At a minimum, you should identify the exact article you are reading. My memory is that we cannot solve the backwards heat equation for all time under all circumstances, but can with adequate restrictions.

Comment: @WillJagy, The paper is "The Entropy Formula for Linear Heat Equation" By Lei Ni. The Journal of Geometric Analysis, Volume 14 , Number 1, 2004. 87-100.  The page that I am reading is bottom of page 91, the proof of Theorem 1.2.

Comment: Here is the link to the paper at Ni's homepage:http://math.ucsd.edu/~lni/academic/ni.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author solves the backward  heat equation $h_t=-\Delta h$ moving backward in time, from initial condition at time $t=t_0>0$ to time $t=0$. This is equivalent, via the change of variable $\tilde t = t_0-t$, to solving the heat equation moving forward in time.